# Can't access fragment after clearing it from back stack

Tags: android, kotlin

I have two flows that can happen in my app: A1->A2->B or A1->B, A and B being different activities, 1 and 2 different fragments. When in B, there's no reason to go back to A2, so I'm using the following code to clear the stack of fragments before starting activity B (startControle()) from A2:

```
requireFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
(activity as MainActivity?)?.startControle()
```

The problem is that when I go back to A1 and try to go to A2, the app crashes

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ufrj.projetointegrado, PID: 23181
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.ufrj.projetointegrado:id/action_inicio_to_btOff cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.ufrj.projetointegrado:id/btOff) label=btOff class=com.ufrj.projetointegrado.btOff
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:938)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:875)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:861)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:849)
        at com.ufrj.projetointegrado.inicio$onCreateView$1.onClick(inicio.kt:31)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6600)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6577)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:781)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25917)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6939)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
```

Anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

EDIT

I also tried this way, but it behaves the same way:

```
val navController = this.findNavController()
navController.popBackStack(R.id.inicio, true);
(activity as MainActivity?)?.startControle()
```

Comment: Why are you directly using `FragmentManager` at all if you are using `NavController` and its `popBackStack()` APIs?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I did try using NavController too, just updated the question.

Comment: Is `R.id.inicio` your `startDestination` of your graph (your 'A1' in your question)? Are you wanting to pop A1 as well (since you're using the inclusive = true)?

Comment: Yes, it is. I just want to pop A2 actually.

Comment: That was it! Thank you @ianhanniballake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, when using Navigation, you must always use the `NavController` APIs - specifically, use `navController.popBackStack()` and **not** the `FragmentManager` APIs directly.

Secondly, passing `true` to `popBackStack()` means an inclusive pop - i.e., also pop the destination you pass in. If you only want to pop A2 while you're on A2, you could

A) Use `popBackStack()` (which pops just the topmost destination)
B) Use `popBackStack()` with the ID of A2 and an inclusive of true
C) Use `popBackStack()` with the ID of A1 and an inclusive of false

Thirdly, while calling `popBackStack()` and then calling `startActivity()` manually is totally fine, you can *also* use a combination of [`popUpTo`](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop) and [activity destinations](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-migrate#add) to pop your destination **and** navigate to an activity as a single operation.

```
<activity
    android:id="@+id/activity_b"
    android:name="com.example.ActivityB" />
```

Then add an action to navigate from A2 to B:

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/a2_to_b"
    app:popUpTo="@+id/inicio"
    app:destination="@+id/activity_b" />
```